# How can I open an application and move it to a specific window stack position with XMonad?

Tags: xmonad

Is there anyway I can make all new applications open in a specific window position?

What I am trying to achieve is open emacs and move it to the master Window, however I only what this action performed on emacs and not other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import qualified XMonad.StackSet                  as W

myManageHook :: Query (Data.Monoid.Endo WindowSet)
myManageHook = composeAll
    [ className =? "Emacs"          --> doF W.swapMaster 
    ]

...
, manageHook =  myManageHook <+> manageHook desktopConfig
...
```